# Latex Error: File `siam10.clo' not found when I compile with Texify and PDFTexify

Tags: errors

recently I had installed Miktex 2.9.3972 because I have an **old** PIII running Windows XP service pack 3, but when I try to compile the `Proof.tex` file, PC gives this result:

```
Command Line:   texify.exe --src --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Mis documentos\BackUp\SS\Proof.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Mis documentos\BackUp\SS

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode

("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrador/Mis documentos/BackUp/SS/Proof.tex"
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.

("C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Mis documentos\BackUp\SS\spani
shsiamltex.cls"
Document Class: spanishsiamltex 1996/10/11 v1.2 LaTeX document class
("C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\leqno.clo")
("C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\leqno.clo")

! LaTeX Error: File `siam10.clo' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: clo)

Enter file name: 

Process has been terminated ...
```

I downloaded `siamltex1213.zip` which includes `siam10.clo` from:

```
https://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php
```

and I copied it to:

```
C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9
```

folder, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what can I do?? 
Thanks, Before Hand!!

Comment: You should either put those files from siamltex1213.zip unpacked in the same directory as the document are trying to compile, or place them in a local texmf tree.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `C:\Archivos de programa\MiKTeX 2.9` is the standard path like `c:\Progamme\MiKTeX 2.9` in a german installation or `c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9` in an english installation.  Then please do **not** manually install files there.

Looking into the named zip file I think the best way is for you to create a **new directory** `MyLaTeX` for your user "MyUser", for example `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\MyLaTeX`.  Then **copy/extract** the files from the zip file into your directory `MyLaTeX`.  Now copy your file `Proof.tex` (and other files you needed for it like images) into the directory `MyLaTeX`.

To test the zip file you can compile file `ex_article.tex` and check the resulting log file for error messages.  That should compile without problems.

Now you can compile your file `Proof.tex`.

At last a tip: First test are easier done, if you use the terminal/console to start the compiling with `pdflatex Proof.tex` for LaTeX etc.

TeXify or PDFTeXify are separate programs and can result in error you will not get with compiling from terminal or start usual compiling (step by step) with your editor.

If you know what an local texmf is (I suggest you to learn the advantages of a localtexmf; there is a question about localtexmf on this web page, please use the search to find it) you can install the content of the zip into your local TeXMF tree.

Because we have not file `Proof.tex` I can not test it and show you the result on my computer ...